# Unity - Command Line Performance

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a simulator, written in Unity 2018.3.11f1, that can be run either in editor mode or unattended from command line. I would like to speed up the performance of the simulator, when it is run unattended. Every N seconds the simulator dumps a screenshot into a specified directory. There is no need to render any frames between screenshots, and I am already using -batchmode and a cache server.

I've tried turning off and stopping the cameras between screenshots, but that did not seem to give any sort of performance increase according to our benchmark, maybe because I am already using -batchmode?

Is there anything else that might improve performance?

Comment: It's pretty hard for us to suggest things to improve performance, if we don't know your application/code or know where the chokepoints are. Have you connected a debugger/profiler to it to find out *what part* of your application is actually causing the performance issues? If you have please post this information so we can go on form there

Comment: `-batchmode` only means: no User interaction and for any error immediately exit with error .. it doesn't really improve performance except not logging that much

Comment: Use the profiler and address any CPU/GPU hotspots